# Authentication and removing the ability to replay information from a compromised machine

Tags: mobile, replay-detection

Consider this scenario.  You have a client machine which is compromised, and a "master" machine which monitors that client's status (IsCompromised = {True|False}).  The client has an agent which checks back into the master at a defined interval in order to relay this information.

Assuming that the client is able to gather the correct information to determine whether or not it has been compromised (think "rooted" or "jailbroken"), how could you ensure that the information from the client being sent to the master machine was not actually sent by a 3rd party machine, nor was it manipulated or replayed?

My initial thoughts are encrypting and signing the message, but in a worst case scenario the certificate on the client is compromised so the signature does not provide authentication (although we could have good encryption between the client and the other side of the TLS connection, we need to be aware that there's a good possibility of a MITM since this machine is compromised... it could trust anything and we have no realistic expectation that the other side is our server).  We also want some sort of session based information or an authenticated hash, but with no secrets on the machine, how can we confidently have that?

For some context, please check out [this article](https://www.netspi.com/blog/entryid/192/bypassing-airwatch-root-restriction).

Of course, we are fighting against the [third immutable law of security](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx#EJAA) here, but I'm trying fully think this through.

Comment: This doesn't answer the title of the question, but in a real life scenario, you could have a computer -which passes those 10 laws- audit the device via a USB connection to determine if there are any problems.  Of course, this could be circumvented if the employee has extreme knowledge of security and the device.  If nothing less, the physical test reduces the chance that they will risk modifying their device.  The phone in their pocket feels anonymous.  Their phone hooked up to a audit server: not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *non-repudiation* is about convincing a third party (a judge): Alice signs a message and sends it to Bob, so that non only Bob is convinced that the message really comes from Alice and was not altered, but Bob can show it to Charlie and Charlie will be convinced, too. Here, you only have a client and a server, no third party, so "non-repudiation" is not relevant here. This more looks like an *authentication* problem.

The first answer is that **it is not possible** on the following grounds: the machine being fully compromised, the attacker could read its entire contents. The attacker may then run a clone of the machine in a virtual machine and let that clone talk with the server. The clone will report that all is well, while the attacker pillages the genuine system. From a cryptographer's point of view, a difference which can be made between two entities, from the outside (e.g. a genuine watchdog, and a fake one), only if they cannot compute the same things, and ability to *compute* equates to *knowledge*: the watchdog can compute an answer to the server that the attacker cannot fake only if the watchdog knows some secret data that the attacker does not, and, by construction, this does not happen.

---

The second answer is that **it might be feasible** but it requires that the conditions are right. If we look at the problem closely, we see that the attacker's goal is to talk with the server, emitting messages that the compromised machine cannot produce. This means that the watchdog can work reliably **only if the compromise is destructive**. For instance, suppose that:

- The client under supervision uses a set of system files (the operating system with its kernel and libraries and utilities).
- Under normal conditions, these files are not entirely known to the attacker (he may have copies of some or most of them, but not all).
- But the server knows all the files, exactly.
- A successful compromise necessarily "damages" at least one file (that's the tricky point) and the modified contents cannot be recovered afterwards by the attacker.

Under these conditions, then you can use the following:

- Make an archive of all the system files, in alphabetical order. The archive format must include the file names and contents and be deterministic: if you make the archive *twice*, you get twice the same output file, exact to the last bit. The archive file is not stored on disk or in RAM; it is hashed on-the-fly with SHA-256.
- Let *K* be the SHA-256 output. At regular intervals, the client talks to the server; the server sends a random challenge *C*, and the client responds with HMAC/SHA-256, computed over *C* and using *K* as key.
- The server uses his knowledge of the client files to recompute *K* and verify the HMAC output.

The challenge-response protocol with HMAC prevents replay attacks. MitM do not apply either. We really are in information-theoretic grounds here, not "normal crypto".

Unfortunately, it is very hard to ensure the conditions above. Secrecy of the device contents is almost impossible to achieve when the device is a consumer product (the attacker can buy other device instances, open them and look at all the contents), and most compromises are *not* destructive, at least as far as system files are involved: buffer overflows and similar vulnerabilities lead to RAM-only exploits, with no change whatsoever to system files.

Therefore what I expose here is more a theoretical concept than anything practical. However, this ought to help understand the issue: to prevent hidden alterations, the watchdog must own a "secret" which will not be revealed through a full compromise, which is kind of paradoxical and requires a bit of cheating with preposterous conditions.